# How to check if two out of three values are the same?

Tags: java

I was wondering how to check if two out of three values are the same. My code right now is:

```
public static boolean twoOutOfThree(int a, int b, int c) {
    if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c)) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

This passes all of the tests that are true however when I test it for (0,0,0), it comes back as true instead of false. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to check that it's *exactly* 2 of the 3 that are equal you need to adjust your conditions accordingly. Right now it only verifies that any 2 are equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all 3 are the same, then `a == b` obviously is also true. So each 3 of the cases also needs to check that the 3rd one is different. So you need to change

```
(a == b || b == c || a == c)
```

to

```
(a == b && b != c) || (b == c && a !=c ) || (a == c && b != c))
```

##### Additional tip

Functions of this form:

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Can be written much shorter by just doing

```
return condition;
```

So the end result is this:

```
public static boolean twoOutOfThree(int a, int b, int c) {
    return ((a == b && b !=c ) || (b == c && a !=c ) || (a == c && b !=c));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-optimized solution.

The `Set` will get rid of duplicates, then just check its final size.

`return new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a,b,c)).size() == 2;`

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra case to your if statement:

```
((a==b) || (b==c) || (a==c) && !(a == b & b == c))
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable called "count"  for example , if any value is equal to another then you increment the count by 1 and then you can check if count is equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

You can count as the following solution

```
public static boolean twoOutOfThree(int a, int b, int c) {
    int count = 0;
    if (a == b) {
       count += 1;
    }
    if (b == c) {
       count += 1;
    }
    if (c == a)
       count += 1;
    }
    if (count == 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Set and add your values in the set. Set always holds unique values only. So if you have 3 numbers and add them to a set and your set length is 3 that none of the numbers are equal to each other. If the length is 2 then 2 numbers where equal and if the length is 1 then all 3 are equal

Answer (score 0):

```
return !(
           (
               (a==b)&&(b==c)
           ) || 
           (
               (a!=b)&&(b!=c)&&(a!=c)
           )
        );
```

Only 10 operators made of

- 3 AND
- 1 OR
- 1 NOT
- 5 comparisons

I don't know if this is fastest. But if CPU core has multiple ALUs each doing comparisons in parallel, then this could get a boost.